# AMD Graphic installition error

Tags: installation, drivers, ati, graphics, error-handling

i got this error when i try to install the amd grapich

> Supported adapter detected.
>   Check if system has the tools required for installation.
>   fglrx installation requires that the system have kernel headers.  /lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/build/include/linux/version.h cannot be found on this system.
>   One or more tools required for installation cannot be found on the system. Install the required tools before installing the fglrx driver.
>   Optionally, run the installer with --force option to install without the tools.
>   Forcing install will disable AMD hardware acceleration and may make your system unstable. Not recommended.

how can i fix it please replay fast ..

Comment: Tip: If you have amd working, don't try to install other drivers, not from amd.com or elsewhere, amd doesn't support people who aren't using windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are running Ubuntu 12.10 which is missing Headers. try installing header file and then installing the driver

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```